# Vue.js conerverting a String into a list

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, string, vue.js

For a project I am working on, I get data from a sql database using php. I get my data inside my javascript code such as: "{"data1":"data2","data3":"data4"}" so this as one string. I want to convert this string into a list so I can display my data with a v-for loop. I have been stuck for a while, any help would be very helpful.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: You can iterate over keys of the object in Vue https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object